# How do i consol.log countRight with this code?

Tags: javascript

```
function rightAnswer() {
  console.log('right')
  var countRight = 0;
  [Button2, Buttonb3].forEach(a =>
    a.addEventListener('click', () => {
      countRight += 1;

    })
  );
}
```

I need help with being able to print `consol.log(countRight)`. So far when i use that line of code the consol always shows countRight = 0 even though it should say either 1 or 2 depending on the users input. I need help with making this code work.

It does not work if i put `consol.log(countRight)` after `countRight += 1;`

Comment: You're logging when you add the event listeners, not after the user clicks.

Comment: Please include all relevant code; what are `Button2` and `Buttonb3`?

Comment: That would not be relevant in this code. They are just buttons

Comment: Put the `console.log()` call inside the event listener function, after `counterRight += 1`

Comment: Sorry for not being specific enough but where ever i put the consol.log() it does not work

Comment: It's `console`, not `consol`

Comment: All variables referenced in this code (and more) are relevant for reproducing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function rightAnswer() {
  var countRight = 0;
  [Button2, Buttonb3].forEach(a =>
    a.addEventListener('click', () => {
      countRight += 1;
      // this is where you should be able to log the value
      console.log(`right value is: ${countRight}`);

    })
  );
}
```

This is spaghetti code though. Your function breaks scope by referencing "Button2", "Buttonb3"

Answer (score 0):

If you want to log on clicks the right place to log is in the click handler.

The implication from naming is that `countRight` will be called to increment the count–as it is no handlers will be added until `countRight` has been called (and it should be called only *once* so multiple handlers aren't added).

It might make more sense to add the handlers on the `load` event. If you *really* mean to add them at an arbitrary time in the future it can certainly be put in a method, noting again it should only be called once, or the event listeners removed before calling it again.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  let countRight = 0

  const button1 = document.getElementById('button1')
  const button2 = document.getElementById('button2')
  const buttons = [button1, button2]

  const output = document.getElementById('output')

  buttons.forEach(b => {
    b.addEventListener('click', b => {
      countRight++
      output.innerText = countRight
      console.log(`countRight = ${countRight}`)
    })
  })
}, false);
```

```html
<button id="button1">Button #1</button>
<button id="button2">Button #2</button>
<div>Clicked <span id="output">0</span> times.</div>
```

---

*Tangential*

The reason to post a complete example is so people can copy it into their answers and actually run it. It also makes sense to